# Rake assets:precompile aborts after CSS3 animation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rake

Two questions: 
1) How can I get rake assets:precompile to work with the CSS3 animations I have in my application.css?

In application.css:

```
@-webkit-keyframes greenPulse {
from { background-color: #749a02; -webkit-box-shadow:: 0 0 9px #333; }
50% { background-color: #91bd09; -webkit-box-shadow:: 0 0 18px #91bd09; }
to { background-color: #749a02; -webkit-box-shadow:: 0 0 9px #333; }
}
```

The error:

```
rake aborted!
Invalid CSS after "...kit-box-shadow:": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was ": 0 0 9px #333; }"
```

**EDIT** This is fixed by changing :: to :. I still need help with this question though:

2) How can I avoid having to do rake assets:precompile every time I want to update my CSS page in development only?

Comment: Isn't assets pipeline only available in production?

Comment: @Raffaele Maybe so, but then why are my CSS pages only updating if I do rake assets:precompile?

Comment: Can it be a webrick issue? Have you tried restarting it? Just guessing..

Comment: Also, what do those double columns mean there, after the property names?

Comment: @Raffaele Yes, I've restarted webrick haha. Definitely an assets problem, not a server restart. As for the ::, I think that was the problem. I fixed it earlier but I still need answers on the second part though... I should probably update my question though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you need to recompile assets in development mode is that Rails will load your precompiled assets before your changed stuff under `app/assets`.

Generally, you shouldn't need to precompile in development mode at all: just make sure your `public/assets` folder is empty. You can use `rake assets:clean` to get rid of them. Then your development changes should be picked up immediately.

Comment: Actually, interestingly enough, the REAL problem was with Google Chrome caching my CSS page. Not even a Rails problem!